# example of using log collector from my app

Tags: android

the open source Log Collector looks very useful and I would like to integrate it into my app.  Although the source code site mentions a usage example I cant see anything like this except for the mention re usage inside the source code itself.  Is there any other info on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the mention in the source code you were referring to, but there is a full usage example here:
http://code.google.com/p/android-log-collector/source/browse/trunk/android-log-collector-usage/src/com/xtralogic/android/logcollector/usage/Main.java

Comment: Thanks that is what I was looking for.   I believe the log is circular so I am also curious as to what the limit of entries is before overwriting starts.  I'll post this as a new question but if You have any info I would appreciate it.